# URL for webapp Docker Tomcat IntelliJ

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm using a Tomcat 9 server in a Docker container to deploy locally a webapp for development purposes. I can connect to my Tomcat using http://localhost:8080/ [image: Localhost Tomcat]But I can't find my webapp URL anywhere. My Docker container is deployed from IntelliJ, and I have no URL field in the configuration of the Container.[image: IntelliJ Run/Debug Configurations]

Does anyone know where to find/set the URL ?

Comment: By default tomcat will serve the app based on the .war file name. "For example, if you deploy an WAR file called demo.war, it will be made available under the demo context." - https://octopus.com/blog/defining-tomcat-context-paths   or you can override that by adding a context.xml (and define a path=myApp)

Answer (score 1):

There is no URL to be set, at least not explicitly.

Once you have your application started in a container (either started through *IntelliJ IDEA*, *Docker Desktop (for)*, command line...) with the port binding configuration (the *Bind ports* config section in your screenshot), you are only left with the application as if it was started on the host on the mapped port (the first section before the colon `:` in the port binding).

Which means you can simply access your application on:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

following the pattern for a URL: `(protocol)://(host)(:port)` where:

- `protocol` is HTTP since you mentioned using *Tomcat* as a web server
- `host` being you local station where the docker daemon is running on
- `port` being the port you chose to map to the started container port

Comment: So this would mean that the problem is not about the URL, but my code, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add the "Bind mounds" with parameters [YOURS PROJECT PATH]/target:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps
Remember that each time you run this option, a container will be created and there is no need to do so, for example, you can restart the container after collecting a new war.